# Redis still returns null entries even when they are expired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I am using Spring Repositories with Redis and want to store data about user for 10 seconds and expire them (and delete them) from redis.
I know expiring and deleting is different, but is there an easy way to delete them like I am expiring them automatically.

I have the following entity

```
@RedisHash(value = "User", timeToLive = 10)
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Indexed
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "First name of the user")
    private String firstName;
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Last name of the user")
    private String lastName;

    ...
    ...
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {
}
```

Configuration for Redis

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Value("${redis.hostname}")
    private String redisHostname;
    @Value("${redis.port}")
    private int redisPort;

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHostname, redisPort);
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        return template;
    }
}
```

When I get all the entities with findAll method from the repository if they are expired I get a bunch of null values, and I can see that they are in the redis with a redis client. I am worried that this will fill the db with a lot of expired data. Is there a way to delete the expired entities.

Comment: facing the same issue!!
Is there a workaround for this because I am receiving old entries as well..
Expiration time 5 minutes - retrieving old data will null values!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the expiration is set to a positive value, the corresponding EXPIRE command is executed. In addition to persisting the original, a phantom copy is persisted in Redis and set to expire five minutes after the original one.

for more information, please reference [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.repositories.expirations)

Hope [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693774/spring-redis-indexes-not-deleted-after-main-entry-expires) helps you.

Comment: Please consider adding more details in the answer itself and use links as references only.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is:

Put the following annotation:

```
@EnableRedisRepositories(enableKeyspaceEvents = EnableKeyspaceEvents.ON_STARTUP)
```

Above your main class (SpringBootApplication)

Objects will now get removed from the redis store :)